# creating a javascript bookmarklet with variables declared in page

Tags: javascript

absolute novice at js, as a disclaimer.

there's a page that exists that has variables declared such as:

```
c="hello"
cd="12345"
```

and a php viewing script that makes the image only "accessible" (it's hidden under a flash layer otherwise" by a swf that loads:

```
 ((("view.php?cid=" + c) + "&cd=") + cd)
```

so the url ends up looking like

```
 view.php?cid=hello&cd=12345
```

would it be possible to turn this into a javascript bookmarklet?

thanks

-A

EDIT for clarity for Sno0py:

Neither of the pages are my site. It's a site I'm trying to create a bookmarklet for.
On the page, there is flashembed.js, which can be used for a multitude of things, but in this case, in used to make it so you can't right click to save an image (makes it a movie, and with a php view script, puts the image in it).

On the page, there is this html/javascript:

```
<div id="viewer">
    <!-- image is here -->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    flashembed("viewer",
    {src: "overlay.swf"},
    {c: "hello", cd: "123456"}
    );
</script>
```

where #viewer is specified in another js script, and c & cd are randomly generated identifiers for the image.

`overlay.swf` does this:

```
stage.showmenu = false;
loadmovie ((("http://example.com/view.php?cid=" + c) + "&cd=") + cd, _root);
_root.stop();
```

so navigating to `http://example.com/view.php?cid=hello&cd=123456` would yield the raw data for the image. you can view it with `<img src="view.php?cid=hello&cd=123456">` though.

SO: to clarify, would I would like, is a javascript bookmarklet that grabs `c` and `cd`, forms the url, and brings you to a page with just the `<img src"yadayada">` from above. If that's not possible, just bringing me to the `url` would be nice.

Comment: What exactly should the bookmarklet do? And: are c and cd global vars on the page? Otherwise AFAIK you cannot access them.

Comment: It should change from the page you're on to the URL in my OP (last one). c and cd are global.

Comment: In fact it needs to do more even, needs to go to a page with the html source being `<img src='view.php?cid=hello&cid=12345>`. If that makes sense.

Comment: I think I didn't understand, what you want. Could you explain, what you have and what exactly you want to change via the bookmarklet?

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the original post so it's easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

If `c` and `cd` where variables within the scope of the page, you could simply use this bookmarklet:

```
javascript:document.location = "http://example.com/view.php?cid=" + c + "&cd=" + cd;
```

However, they are not. They are attributes of anonymous objects passed as parameters to the function `flashembed`.

If that function then assigned them to variables in a scope that the bookmarklet could access, then you could use those variables instead, but I seriously doubt that it does.

You are basically left then with the only other option, which is to parse the raw HTML of the page (`document.documentElement.outerHTML`), most likely with a regular expression.